# Add additional class to Pinterest Pin It Button iframe

Tags: javascript, class, iframe, pinterest

I'm having an issue with the Pinterest Pin it button.  The [Pinterest JS](http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#code) creates an `iframe` by default.  However the `iframe` is creating unwanted space in my footer.  I'm trying to resolve the unwanted spacing by hiding the `iframe`.  I can't hide all `iframe`s since there are others on the page needed.  Also the `class` in the `iframe` constantly changes so I can't use that.

Is there a way to add either an additional `class` or `ID` to the dynamically loaded `iframe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target it like this:

```
iframe[src^="//assets.pinterest"] {
 display: none;
}
```